# Copy to clipboard javascript function not working

Tags: javascript

I'm using another post's JS Fiddle to copy text from the DOM to the clipboard, which works in Google Chrome but not Safari.

Here's the [link](https://jsfiddle.net/jdhenckel/km7prgv4/3)

HTML

```
<button onclick="copyToClip(document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML)">
  Copy the stuff
  </button>

<div id="foo" style="display:none">
  This is some data that is not visible. 
  You can write some JS to generate this data. 
  It can contain rich stuff.
  <b> test </b> me <i> also </i>
  <span style="font: 12px consolas; color: green;">Hello world</span> You can use setData to put TWO COPIES into the same clipboard, one that is plain and one that is rich. That way your users can paste into either a
  <ul>
    <li>plain text editor</li>
    <li>or into a rich text editor</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
function copyToClip(str) {
  function listener(e) {
    e.clipboardData.setData("text/html", str);
    e.clipboardData.setData("text/plain", str);
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  document.addEventListener("copy", listener);
  document.execCommand("copy");
  document.removeEventListener("copy", listener);
};
```

Comment: `id=foo` should be inside of quotes: `id="foo"`

Comment: Updated the html based on your feedback, still the same result in Safari though.

Comment: @ChristianCarrillo — `foo` contains no special characters that would require it to be quoted in an attribute value.